# How to detect when one file is modified inside a symbolic link directory in Linux

Tags: c, linux

I have a symbolic link to one directory like this

```
root@beaglebone:/sys/class/drm#    
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 0 Sat Jan 1 00:00:01 2000 card0-HDMI-A-1 -> /sys/devices/ocp.3/4830e000.lcdc/drm/card0/card0-HDMI-A-1
```

How can I detect/watch when one file is modified inside the real path (/sys/devices/ocp.3/4830e000.lcdc/drm/card0/card0-HDMI-A-1) which the symbolic link (/sys/class/drm/card0-HDMI-A-1) points to.

(I prefer a C program to do this).

Thanks much.

Comment: [inotify](http://linux.die.net/man/7/inotify).

Comment: Seem that inotify doesn't work in case of watching a symbolic link, thanks.

Comment: inotify does work on sym links. If you can't get it to work please post the code that you are trying with.

Comment: Thanks for your help, Alan Au. Inotify works on sym link. I will recheck my program.

Answer (score 0):

The command you are looking for is [stat](http://linux.die.net/man/2/stat). `stat` retrieves data about a file (in *nix, a directory is a kind of file). When used on a symbolic link, `stat` will return data on what the link points to, not the link itself. `stat` populates a `struct stat`, whose `st_mtime` member is the time of the last modification, which for a directory, will update when its contents change.

```
struct stat file_info;

if ( stat ( "/sys/class/drm/card0-HDMI-A-1", &file_info ) == 0 ) {
  /* stat succeeded, file_info.st_mtime is the real directory's mod time */
} else {
  /* stat failed for some reason. consult the man page for info about error codes */
}
```